# Do we really need the "Android-Independent" close reason?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

The "general<sup>1</sup> off-topic" explanation text already says

> Questions on Android Enthusiasts should be asked from a end-user point of view and **within the scope defined in the [help center](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic.)**.

And under the "**What about other Android-related questions?**" section, we have this for the 7<sup>th</sup> item

> - Android-independent questions, such as "Does Carrier X have prepaid plans?"

I think it's more straightforward to close as the reason of "general off-topic", and optionally leave a comment to tell OP to read [help center](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic.). Furthermore both reasons are rarely used so I think it'd be cleaner to merge them.

---

<sup>1. All SE sites have a similar close reason to this.</sup>

Comment: While I can follow that line, this way you could argue we only need "off topic" without sub-sections – as development, off-site resources and belongs elsewhere are also clearly outsite the scope of our site. We still have them so the user gets a better understanding *from the start.* Especially as most of them start arguing before "checking the scope" ;)

Comment: The problem is, that's only a reason to flag, not to close. Users who vote to close doesn't have this reason as a choice. Either they choose from the available reasons, or they write a custom reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This close reason is designed to let people know not to ask about general phone issues or generic hardware issues, rather than the much broader "something not in scope".  We get quite a lot of these questions, and approximately 0.1% of their askers bother to read the help center.  A slightly larger number read the close reason, so I'd say it's helpful.

We also tend to get people who argue based on things like "well I'm using an Android phone with Sprint, so Sprint's coverage areas are relevant!" and this shuts them down much more effectively than the help center.

Unless you have an idea for a more useful close reason to take the spot of this one, I don't see any reason to take action to remove it.